# building a program without needing to .glade source

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

I am programming something using C and Gtk+ library via Glade
I'm Compiling with a "makefile" methode and everything it is ok
but when I change the application.exe folder (like sending it to my friend) the application doesn't work
my question is there any way to compile it without needing to the glade file in the same folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out [GResource](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResource.html), which lets you embed files such as a Glade file into your executable.

Comment: can you give me a simple example 
assume 
 GtkBuilder *builder;
     builder = gtk_builder_add_from_file("glade/main_window.glade");
does this work ?

Comment: and thank you by the way for giving a hand of help 
I am not native English speaker sorry

Comment: or if you have any tutorial to learn about currently gtk versions

Comment: `add_from_file` isn't going to work unless the file is in the right place. You need `add_from_resource`.

Comment: it doesn't work with .glade file

Comment: can you give some hints please

Comment: There's an example of including files in a GResource in the GTK sample sources: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/tree/master/examples/bp

Comment: okey thanks and sorry